# Funcion para calcular un promedio con filtro de fecha en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

tardes o noches, la siguiente es para pedir una pequeña ayuda, resulta que tengo una tabla de evaluacion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] de la cual saco la informacion para calcular mi promedio.

El problema radica en el filtro de mi funcion de MySQL la cual es:

```
FUNCTION promedioAbyFechaCurso(idCourse int, Fecha varchar(50)) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
BEGIN
Declare A, cont, r decimal(10,2);
set A=(SELECT sum(car1) FROM Evaluacion where id_curso like idCourse and fecha like concat(Fecha, '%%'));
set cont=(select count(*) from Evaluacion where id_curso like idCourse and date(fecha) like concat(date(Fecha), '%%'));
set r=((A/cont)/10)*100;
RETURN r;

END
```

Se supone que cuando inserte el idCourse y la fecha esta funcion deberia seleccionarme el car1 de la tabla evaluacion y sumarme dicha columna teniendo en cuenta el WHERE utilizado, pero cuando aplico el filtro por la fecha, sea cual sea la fecha que introduzca, siempre me suma todo lo que exista en dicho car pero con el idCourse aplicado.

Lo que yo necesito es que me tenga en cuenta los dos filtros, en otras palabras si hay data con el idCourse 1 por ejemplo en la fecha 2020-01-01, pero los parametros que yo le envio son idCourse 1 y FECHA 2020-09-01 me mande 0 o null ya que en si esa data no existe, pero si aplico el filtro por idCourse 1 y la FECHA en el 2020-01-01 me aplique el calculo correspondiente y me mande el resultado que es.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen, te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Gracias por el consejo

Comment: Por lo que veo, tu where es "id_curso like idCourse" y en lo personal, interpreto el funcionamiento de eso de la siguiente manera, si le envias la "idCoruse" que es el parametro, con valor '1', pero existen id_course 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, los contara en el registro, ya que Poseen el parametro enviado, 1.
Te recomiendo utilizar la igualación de ids directamente.

Comment: ¿Estas almacenando fechas como VARCHAR? Usa DATE. Además, en lugar de hacer sum y count usa `avg`.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, me ha funcionado lo mencionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te indican en los comentarios, al usar `like` en la cláusula `where` el query puede tomar cualquier valor que contenga el número que le hayas pasado. En su lugar, debes usar `where id_curso = 1`

```
SELECT SUM(car1) FROM Evaluacion WHERE id_curso = 1 AND fecha = 2020-01-10
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda